# ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl - Unknown KieSession name: in drools 6.2.0

Tags: maven, drools

I am simply trying to run the helloWorld example from the Git repo : 
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/master/drools-examples/src/main/java/org/drools/examples/helloworld

For this I created a Drools project in IntelliJ 14.1.5
JDK - 1.7

When I try and run the HelloWorld file from IntelliJ I get the below error:

```
[main] ERROR org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl - Unknown KieSession name: HelloWorldKS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at main.java.org.drools.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldExample.execute(HelloWorldExample.java:37)
    at main.java.org.drools.examples.helloworld.HelloWorldExample.main(HelloWorldExample.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I have the kmodule.xml present in resources/META-INF folder.
I also have pom.properties file containing the correct group and artifactId.

Have I missed anything specific?

Comment: I didn't try to reproduce but this: `at main.java.org` looks _really_ weird, as if the main source folder were `src` instead of `src/main/java`. I don't know IntelliJ but maybe the Maven setup is incorrect.

Comment: Line #37 of the link you posted is a comment :|

Answer (score 0):

I hit similar problems. When you start running, the KieContainer will be found in the target directory. So, you need to build your project and configure your `pom.xmlif`. Your target has the `kmodule.xml`, you will see the hello world.
[image]

[image]